# Query SQL table whose table name has space in between in VBA Excle

Tags: sql, excel, vba

The below code I have two query listed stSQL = "SELECT * FROM QA\Dependencies" and stSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM QA\QA Priority" If you see the 1st query when i run that its runs smoothly but if run the other query where the table name or you can view name of a lotus notes has spaces in them it gives me an error. Can any one help with writing a for Lotus not view whose name have space in them.

```
  Option Explicit
  Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
  Dim wbBook As Workbook
  Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
  Dim rnData As Range
  Dim adoCN As ADODB.Connection
  Dim adoRst As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim adoRst1 As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim stSQL As String
  Dim stSQL1 As String
  Dim vaData As Variant
  Dim a As String

  Set adoCN = New ADODB.Connection
  Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
  Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  adoCN.Open ("Driver={Lotus NotesSQL Driver (*.nsf)};Database=DATABASE.nsf;Server=Server;")
  stSQL = "SELECT * FROM QA\Dependencies"
  Set adoRst = adoCN.Execute(stSQL)
  stSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM QA\QA Priority"
  Set adoRst1 = adoCN.Execute(stSQL1)
  adoCN.Close
  Set adoRst = Nothing
  Set adoRst1 = Nothing
  Set adoCN = Nothing
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to surround your table name with `[]` like so:

```
stSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM [QA\QA Priority]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be referenced as follows:

```
stSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM QA\[QA Priority]"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM QA\[QA Priority]" 'is not working
```

I tried below combination.
    stSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM "
    stSQL2 = stSQL1 & """QA\QA Priority"""